# Entity model assembly build on command line

Tags: entity-framework, entity

Is there an alternate way of building an entity framework assembly (i.e. with csdl, storage and mapping resouces) at the command line (i.e. csc etc) without the use of msbuild. Our build process and environment is a bit out of date.

Comment: Can you be clearer about what it is you're trying to build. `csc.exe` will compile your assembly. What problem are you trying to solve? Are you trying to run EF code generation?

Comment: Sure; I'm trying to build an entity framework assembly which already has a static edmx file (i.e. I'm not looking to dynamically generate this file). It's not like you can specifiy an edmx file as part of the csc.exe source files arguments. I assume there's some additional step, to generate what appears to be entity resource files that would typically be included from an msbuild or visual studio build (just not sure what that specific command line is).

Comment: Previously we were generating the assembly only referencing the design.cs file but comparing the contents in reflector, there's a missing resource directory that would normally contain the EF mapping and model files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using msbuild instead...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but If you do need to use csc you can use the /resource switch to embed files in the output assembly.